# Visual Studio 2013 RTM install hangs

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have been trying to install the new Visual Studio 2013 Professional RTM all day, and the installation keeps hanging at the same place every time.

I have been searching high and low for help resources for this and can find absolutely nothing, so this is kind of my last resort.

The system configuration is as follows;

Windows 8.1 RTM 64-bit Professional
Intel i7 CPU
8 GB RAM

I am trying to install with only the C++ Foundation Classes, Web Developer Tools, and SQL Developer Tools.

I continue to get locked up at this part of the process.

[image]

Comment: Also i'm trying and get stuck at this point, even my Visual studio 2013 ultimate downloaded it from Microsoft web site, I hope you find a solution because my Laptop configuration like yours except I'm using win 8.1 x64 ultimate.

Comment: I've also had trouble installing Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition with Update 4. The installation process has been running for over 24 hours now. It hangs at "Applying" at about 95%.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to confirm is that the hash for your downloaded ISO matches that published by Microsoft. Since ISO's don't have built-in CRC checking, this is a common problem. Depending on the source of your download (MSDN, download.microsoft.com, etc.) the SHA1 hash is usually published along with the download. On MSDN Subscriber downloads click on Details for the relevant download.

If that doesn't help, please contact Microsoft Support (http://support.microsoft.com) for assistance.

Hope that helps.